# Appended anchor tag click event does not adding active class to it. (appended tag is generated by click event of another anchor tag)

Tags: jquery, html

Thanks in advance for help.

You can better understand problem by observing following code:

```
<a class="save-btn" href="#">Save</a>

<ul><li><a href="#">link 1</a></li></ul>

$('.save-btn').click(function() {
    $('ul').append('<li><a class="newLink" href="#">link 2</a></li>')
    return false;
})

$('.newLink').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active') // ".newLink" is not adding "active class"
   return false;
});
```

I want to simply add active class to **link** having class name "myLink" by click event.

**I know the problem** is "click event", appended anchor tag on **window.load** is adding active class perfectly.

[Here is image for more clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJx83.gif)

**Image Description:** Link "Abc Xyz" should add "active class" on click (active link will have blue background according to my image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you bind the click event to `$('.newLink')`, there is no link with that class in the page yet. Use this to bind on any current or future elements matching the selector:
`$(document).on('click', '.newLink', yourcallbackfunction);`

Comment: Thank you so much Connum :)